# Redis performance on m4.large AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

We conducted benchmarking tests on t2.medium and got following througput

```
t2.medium
SET  : 155545.19
GET  : 155775.38
```

when the benchmarking tests with same redis configuration was done on m4.large, the througput decreased to following

```
m4.large
SET : 111788.46
GET : 110503.34
```

What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

T2 instances are never good for benchmarking.

T2 instances are burstable performance instances that provide a baseline level of CPU performance.

The performance and ability to burst are governed by CPU Credits. T2 instances accrue CPU Credits when they are idle, and use CPU credits when they are active.

Please refer to the following documentation to understand performance of T2 instances

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html

Comment: Thanks, they don't give reliable statistics.